# how to create a list with the names generated by paste function?

Tags: r, list, paste

The following code failed. Is there any way to create a list object by creating each element name with paste function?

```
> list(paste("rer","erer")=1:4)
Error: unexpected '=' in "list(paste("rer","erer")="
```

what I want to get is the following list object, but the name should be created with paste because I have two string object.

```
> list("rer erer"=1:4)
$`rer erer`
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setNames` like this:

```
setNames(list(1:4), paste("rer","erer"))
## $`rer erer`
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

or

```
`names<-`(list(1:4), paste("rer","erer"))
## $`rer erer`
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

or

```
L <- list(1:4)
names(L) <- paste("rer","erer")
L
## $`rer erer`
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```